# Convert 2D table to three 1D arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have data in an `n x m` 2D table like this:

[image]

In my Python code, it looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

xData = np.array([-225,    -200,   -175])
yData = np.array([0.1,     1.0,    5.0])
zData = np.array([[749.36, 698.96, 471.88],
                  [1012.1, 987.87, 890.69],
                  [1283.9, 1270.1, 1217.1]])
```

In order to do some curve fitting, I would like to have it in the form of three 1D arrays where each has the size `1 x (n x m)`:

```
xData = np.array([-225,   -225,   -225,   -200,   -200,   -200,   -175,   -175,   -175])
yData = np.array([0.1,    1.0,    5.0,    0.1,    1.0,    5.0,    0.1,    1.0,    5.0])   
zData = np.array([749.36, 698.96, 471.88, 1012.1, 987.87, 890.69, 1283.9, 1270.1, 1217.1])
```

What is a nice and clean way to achieve this?
Note that in general, `xData` and `yData` are not evenly spaced.

Comment: [np.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [np.tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) are your friends.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. I'll add an answer based on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
xData = np.repeat(xData, np.shape(zData)[1])
yData = np.tile(yData, np.shape(zData)[0])
zData = np.reshape(zData, (1, np.size(zData)))
```